# Can't load REcaptcha in any of my browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-8.1, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with a computer, for some reason it won't display the REcaptcha, no matter the browser I'm using.

- I made sure JS is working
- Java is fully updated
- Browsers(Chrome, FireFox, IE) are up to date.
- I even deactivated my firewall and antivirus

None of them have worked. Can someone point me on the right direction?

Comment: The thing is that this is the only computer in the network with this problem, the rest work just fine. @Ramhound

Comment: We've checked for malwares, spywares and viruses already @Ramhound

Comment: No change @Ramhound

Comment: Are you using any content/ad-blocking extensions? Also, check your HOSTS file.

Comment: No we don't have ad-blocking extensions. What should I look for in the HOSTS file? The page loads its just the reCaptcha that doesn't @galacticninja

Comment: Just check if the HOSTS file has malware-looking entries (redirects for unknown sites). Also, does the issue only occur on a single computer? What about other computers on the same network?

Comment: I've only ran scans for malware, not the HOSTS file, let me check. And yes I do mention this is the only computer with this problem in the network in the comments above. @galacticninja

Comment: Are you a robot? Captcha reportedly doesn't work for robots.